# How to convert an ARGB byte[] to BufferedImage

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage

I have a `byte[]` that contains ARGB image data directly. I am trying to find the most performant way to transform this into a `BufferedImage` without unnecessary iterations, essentially I'd like to configure the `BufferedImage` with the right raster and color model to use this memory area directly.

My current approach is this:

```
BufferedImage toBufferedImageAbgr(int width, int height, byte[] abgrData) {
        int bitMasks[] = new int[]{0xf};
        DataBuffer dataBuffer = new DataBufferByte(abgrData, width * height * 4, 0);
        int[] masks = new int[]{0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
        DirectColorModel byteColorModel = new DirectColorModel(8,
                0xff,       // Red
                0xff,       // Green
                0xff,       // Blue
                0xff        // Alpha
        );

        SampleModel sampleModel = new SinglePixelPackedSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, masks);
        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, dataBuffer, null);

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(byteColorModel, raster, false, null);
        return image;
    }
```

I keep playing around with the color model, the bands and all that but can't figure out what's the right configuration for this relatively simple problem.

When I inspect the output image, it unfortunately looks bad, it's a grayscale image with patterns:

[image]

Here is the original image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BufferedImage toBufferedImageAbgr(int width, int height, byte[] abgrData) {
        DataBuffer dataBuffer = new DataBufferByte(abgrData, width * height * 4, 0);
        ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB),
                new int[] {8,8,8,8}, true, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(
                dataBuffer, width, height, width * 4, 4, new int[] {3, 2, 1, 0}, null);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, null);
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: Remove `, 0` from the `DataBufferByte`